# .std() & .skew() giving wrong answer with .rolling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am using pandas version: '0.23.4'

While debugging my code I realized that, std & skew is not giving correct results with rolling window.
Check the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(5)))
df_w = df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1)

m1 = df_w.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))
m2 = df_w.mean()

s1 = df_w.apply(lambda x: np.std(x))
s2 = df_w.std()

sk1 = df_w.apply(lambda x: sp.skew(x))
sk2 = df_w.skew()
```

Though the results for mean is same, but not for std and skew?
Is this expected behavior or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the specified delta degrees of freedom.

`Numpy` uses `ddof` [to be 0 as default](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), while pandas uses `ddof` [to be 1 as default](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html). This value impacts how your `std` is calculated (specifically, how you normalize it, e.g. refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation))

If you specify it to be 0 in both, results are the same

```
s1 = df_w.apply(lambda k: np.std(k, ddof=0), raw=True)
s2 = df_w.std(ddof=0)

>>> (s1==s2).all()
True
```

Similarly, for `skew`, pandas calculates the [*unbiased* skewness](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.skew.html), while `scipy` [calculates the biased.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html)

Therefore, to get the same results, just specify `bias=False` in `scipy`

```
sk1 = df_w.apply(lambda x: sp.skew(x, bias=False))
sk2 = df_w.skew()

>>> (sk1==sk2).all()
True
```

Comment: Hey Rafael, thank you so much, thats exactly the case with std. Any idea about skew ?

Comment: @Abhishek I have edited ;) In the end, it is all about calculating the biased or unbiased estimator